# A technical question about root systems

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

I'm studying root systems and coming up with an observation:

Let $\Phi$ be an irreducible root system and $\Phi^+$ be a positive root system. Denote by $\Delta=\{\alpha_1, \alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n\}$ be the corresponding base. For $\beta, \gamma \in \Phi^+$, $\alpha_1, \alpha_2 \in \Delta$ with the properties that $\beta=\gamma +\alpha_1+\alpha_2$, $\gamma +\alpha_1 \in \Phi^+, \gamma +\alpha_2\in \Phi^+, \alpha_1+ \alpha_2 \notin  \Phi^+$ then

> Statement: There exists $\alpha_3 \in \Delta\setminus\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2\}$ such that either $\gamma +\alpha_1-\alpha_3 \in \Phi^+$ or $\gamma +\alpha_2-\alpha_3 \in \Phi^+$.

The motivation is to investigate the relationship between a positive positive root and other lower positive roots. That is to understand the so-called *Hasse diagram* root systems (for instance see definition of Hasse diagram in [here](http://www.rug.nl/research/portal/files/14628596/03_c3.pdf))

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you say anything at all about what motivates this rather technical formulation?    Also, you seem to be tacitly assuming that $n \geq 3$.    Since it's possible to get a rigorous answer just by checking the irreducible root systems case-by-case, maybe that's a better starting point than just taking a quick look.   [By the way, the header is not informative.   Maybe just try something like "A technical question about root systems"?]

Comment: The original title wasn't great but "A technical question about..." is a quite poor choice of title too.

Comment: @user: My proposed $E_7$ counterexample is not quite right, but if I have time I'll check further.   Anyway, it's best to look at all possibilities first.   Springer's tables are useful for most of the exceptional types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the root system $\mathsf{B}_n$ with the standard numbering of the fundamental roots (that is, $\alpha_n$ is short). Take $\alpha_{n-2}$ and $\alpha_n$ as a pair of orthogonal roots (indeed, $\alpha_{n-2}+\alpha_n$ is not a root), and take $\gamma=\alpha_{n-1}+\alpha_n$. Then $\beta_1=\alpha_{n-2}+\alpha_{n-1}+\alpha_n$, $\beta_2=\alpha_{n-1}+2\alpha_n$ and $\alpha_{n-2}+\alpha_{n-1}+2\alpha_n$ are all roots. But among the differences of the form $\beta_i-\alpha_j$ the only roots are $\beta_1-\alpha_{n-2}$, $\beta_1-\alpha_n$ and $\beta_2-\alpha_n$, so this gives a counter-example.

The beautiful pictures of Hasse diagrams you refer to provide a good way to spot such examples, but for this one should draw them in a different way, which is easier to read. The keyword here is a *weight diagram*. For examples, see [this collection](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.30.5052) of the diagrams along with a description of their various usages.

Namely, Figure 14 on page 35 is the weight diagram of the adjoint representation of a group (or of a Lie algebra) of type $\mathsf{B}_n$, which also describes the structure of the root system (its vertices are the roots, plus the "zero weights" corresponding to the fundamental roots). One looks for a square which has non-consecutive label on its sides (say $i$ and $j$), such that the bonds joining its top or bottom vertex to something on the right are also labeled by either $i$ or $j$. Such a square is immediately found on the very bottom of the picture slightly to the left from the middle.

By the way, the quick inspection of the weight diagrams shows that there is no counter-examples besides the one above (I'm not sure, but I haven't spotted any).

Comment: It may be just me, but I'm afraid of Citeseer links since a long-ago reorganisation rendered many of them useless (and the link text doesn't always give any clue where the link is supposed to point).  I think that the relevant article is [Plotkin, Semenov, and Vavilov - Visual basic representations](http://dx.doi.org/10.1142/S0218196798000053) ([MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1492062)).

Comment: @LSpice I don't appreciate Citeceer much, but I also don't like the links that lead to a paywall. So here is another link: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2418766_Visual_Basic_Representations_An_Atlas

Comment: @MatthiasWendt [points out](http://mathoverflow.net/a/229698/2383) that the paper is also available, (presumably) with Plotkin's blessing, from [his publications page](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~plotkin/publications.html); specifically, at http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~plotkin/papers/atlas_ijac.pdf .