# References about Hasse diagrams of root systems

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

This is to ask about references of *Hasse diagrams* of irreducible root systems. I found [here](http://www.rug.nl/research/portal/files/14628596/03_c3.pdf) and [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E6_%28mathematics%29#/media/File:E6HassePoset.svg) nice pictures of root systems of type $E$. I would like to ask for Hasse diagrams of classical root systems ($A_n, B_n, C_n, D_n$).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For type $A_{n-1}$ just take the strictly upper-triangular part of an $n\times n$ matrix and turn it on its side so that the first upper-diagonal is horizontal and the top right-hand corner of the matrix is now at the top. Then draw edges between position $(i,j)$ and positions $(i+1,j)$ and $(i,j+1)$. For the other classical types you can do something very similar.

Comment: Sorry, between position $(i,j)$ and positions $(i-1,j)$ and $(i,j+1)$ (whenever these make sense).

Comment: This paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.1593 by Ringel describes the posets for all the classical types, and has nice pictures for the exceptionals.

Comment: @HughThomas Thanks. The paper contains pictures of up to rank-6 classical root systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I put a [LaTeX package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lie-hasse) up on CTAN today to draw the Hasse diagrams of all root systems, following Ringel's pictures. Code is as simple as

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lie-hasse}
\begin{document}
\hasseDiagrams{A4;B5}
\hasseDiagrams{F4;G2}
\end{document}
```

to display
[image: Four examples of Hasse diagrams of root systems]

Comment: That's awesome! And you also made dynkin-diagram package! That's gonna make my life so much easier! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but it seems that your code above doesn't work for me. The console says 
Argument of \lie@hasse@place@root has an extra }.
<inserted tex>
  \par
l.5 \hasseDiagrams{F4;G2}

Comment: @user: I tried running that code again to check that it works. I don't have a problem with it, but that might have to do with the particular TeX configuration on my machine. I am using pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian), LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>. If you try to update your system to the latest version of TeXLive or MikTex, please let me know if you still have trouble.

Comment: I am using TeXShop. First it said the dynkin-diagrams.sty file is missing. I found that such a file can be downloaded here https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/dynkin-diagrams?lang=en. I simply put dynkin-diagrams.sty in the same folder with lie-hasse, create a new tex file, copy paste your code and compile. However, still it doesn't produce the desired figures.

Comment: @user:I don't have a Mac, so I can't try out my package on TeXshop. It seems that TeXshop runs with a basic TeX installation, which you can extend to a full TeXLive installation, using the latest TeXLive version, by use of some Mac installer. If that doesn't help, please let me know.

Answer (score 5):

Hasse diagrams for root systems can be extracted from the following paper, which can be found on [E. Plotkin's publication page](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~plotkin/publications.html):

- E.Plotkin, A.Semenov, N.Vavilov, Visual basic representations: An atlas, Int.Journal of Algebra and Computation, 8 (1998), no. 1, 61-95.

The paper discusses more generally Hasse diagrams for the weights of various representations and various applications. The pictures for the adjoint representations give the Hasse diagram of the root system (but using all roots, not just the positive ones).

Comment: I am aware of that paper. It's an excellent reference but containing only Hasse diagrams of weights. I was actually looking for Hasse diagrams which draw positive roots. That helps me easier to read from.

Comment: Well, I mentioned the paper because the difference between all roots and the positive ones should merely be cutting off "in the middle".

Answer (score 0):

I did some research relating to this area for:

[$5$ dimensional space over $\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259887/5-dimensional-space-over-mathbbr)

There isn't much to be found on the Internet other than at Wikipedia, except for:

[A FAMILY OF MARKED CUBIC SURFACES AND THE ROOT SYSTEM $D_5$](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.236.8252), by Elisabetta Colombo and Bert Van Geemen

which is detailed but has no pictures.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I can find Hasse diagram of $D_5$ in the first reference that I gave at the OP. Type $A_n$ is probably is an easiest object to understand. I need bigger/general pictures for other types.